# Related interfaces with typing, but different required properties

Tags: typescript

This is a pattern I encounter with some frequency with the API I work with. I have some object that, depending on some type (described in a property) will have some properties that are always required, some that are always optional and some that are only required (or present at all) when it's some specific type. I usually have being solving it like so (and maybe it will be easier to understand with some code):

```js
export type FoobarTypes = 'foo' | 'bar';

export interface FooBarBase {
  id:        string;
  type:      FoobarTypes;
  optional?: any;
}

export interface FooBarFoo extends FooBarBase {
  foo: any;
}

export interface FooBarBar extends FooBarBase {
  bar: any;
}


export type FooBar = FooBarFoo | FooBarBar;


// and to differentiate between the types:

export const isFooBarFoo  = (foobar: FooBar): foobar is FooBarFoo  =>
  (foobar as FooBarFoo).type === 'foo';

export const FooBarBar  = (foobar: FooBar): foobar is FooBarBar  =>
  (foobar as FooBarBar).type === 'bar';
```

It works fairly well, but I feel like it's a bit over complicated, and that there should be a better, more proper way to achieve it. Or is it the way to go?

---

**Edit**: This is just a further simplification over the accepted answer by @Fyodor. I'm just putting it here so it's easier to refer to than in the comments, in case someone has the same question. His answer is still correct and I wouldn't have gotten to my version if not for his.

```js
export type FoobarTypes = 'foo' | 'bar';

// all of the shared properties go here
export interface FooBarBase {
  id:        string;
  optional?: any;
}

// append the other, specific properties depending on type
export type FooBar<T extends FoobarTypes> =
  T extends 'foo' ? FooBarBase & {
    type: T;
    foo:  any;
  } : T extends 'bar' ? FooBarBase & {
    type: T;
    bar:  any;
  } : never;


// and the usage...
function FB(fb: FooBar<FoobarTypes>) {
  if (fb.type === 'foo') fb.foo = '1';
  if (fb.type === 'bar') fb.bar = '2';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) and generics. This allows you have completly different types depending on `type` property type.

```
export type FoobarTypes = 'foo' | 'bar';

type FooBarBase<T extends FoobarTypes> =
    T extends 'foo' ? 
    {
        id: string;
        type: T;   // T is 'foo'
        optional?: any;
        foo: any;
    } :
        T extends 'bar' ?
    {
        id: string;
        type: T;   // T is 'bar'
        optional?: any;
        bar: any;
    } : never;

type Foo = FooBarBase<'foo'>
type Bar = FooBarBase<'bar'>

function FB(fb: Foo | Bar) {
    if (fb.type === 'foo') {
        fb.foo = '1'   // TS knows, that fb has foo prop and doesn't have bar
    }
    else
    {
        fb.bar = '2'   // Here is opposite. fb only has 'bar'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I figure you can simplify even yet by doing something like `interface FooBarBase { id: string; optional?: any; }

type FooBar<T extends FoobarTypes> = T extends 'foo' ? FooBarBase & { type: T; foo: any; } : T extends 'bar' ? FooBarBase & { type: T; bar: any; } : never;'

and you can use it like: `fb: FooBar<FoobarTypes>`;